# Increment element at index

Tags: arrays, elm, option-type

I am working on the [guide.elm-lang website](https://guide.elm-lang.org/) on the [Random example](https://guide.elm-lang.org/effects/random.html). 
I am trying to add a feature that shows you the total number of times you threw the dice, and some stats on how many times you got each face.

To do this I've changed the model to look like this:

```
type alias Model =
  { 
    die_face : Int,
    total_throws : Int,
    stats: Array.Array Int
  }
```

and this is what I do to update the model:

```
{ model | 
     die_face = face, 
     total_throws = model.total_throws + 1, 
     stats = Array.set face ((Array.get face model.stats) + 1) model.stats
}
```

this throws an error that tells me:

> This `get` call produces:
>
> ```
> #Maybe# Int
> ```
>
> But (+) only works with #Int# and #Float# values.

Which refers to `Array.get` not returning a `Int` but a `Maybe` and therefore I can't add it to the number 1.

I have tried using lists to achieve the same purpose but since they are not indexed I am not sure what to increment when I map over it. I am thinking of using records to do this and figure out a way to map the record keys to the `face` Int.

In general my question is. What is a good method to increment an element at index [x] of an Array in elm ? Or if I am just thinking about this wrong, what would be the elm way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array.get` returns a `Maybe` because it has to account for the case where the index is outside the array. The simplest way of getting around that is using `Maybe.withDefault` with a reasonable default value:

```elm
Array.set face (((Array.get face model.stats) |> Maybe.withDefault 0) + 1) model.stats
```

It might be a good idea to write a helper function for this though, to clean up the code a bit. Something like this:

```elm
incrementAt : Int -> Array Int -> Array Int
incrementAt index array =
    case Array.get index array of
        Just value ->
            Array.set index (value + 1) array

        Nothing ->
            array
```

You can also use [`Array.Extra.update`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/array-extra/latest/Array-Extra#update) if you don't mind the extra dependency.